# ReferenceError: requre is not defined

Tags: node.js, express, cloud9

I am using express and I have installed it using command `npm install express` 
but the require error is occurring every time I try to start my file.

Please help, and thank you in advance.

Error occurs in this function:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { var express = requre("express");
```

Error I am getting:

```
ReferenceError: requre is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/workspace/introtoexpress/app.js:1:77)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:389:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:504:3
```

Comment: `requre`? I think it's `require`

Comment: Yeah you got a typo in there

Answer (score 2):

You might have a typo in your code when you import some module,it's `require` not `requre`